# A field in my app has 2 html codes. When I use OR in its Xpath then it is not detecting the Element. Can anyone help me making an appropriate xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-2.0, xpathnavigator

A field in my application has two HTML codes. I want to use OR in its XPath so that in any HTML code the command can run. But I am unable to use OR in the xpath. It's not detecting the field when I use OR. Below are both the two HTML code. Can anyone make an XPath using OR so that it runs always?
First HTML Code-

```
 <input autocomplete="off" class="text" maxlength="30" tabindex="2" type="password" id="pswd-input" name="password" onfocus="   pswdLabel.style.display='none';pswdWrap.style.margin='0'    " onblur="if(this.value==''){pswdLabel.style.display='block';pswdWrap.style.margin='0 0 -14px'}else{pswdWrap.style.margin='0'} ">
```

and this is Second HTML code-

```
 <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="35;" autocomplete="off" size="37" value="">==$0
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Hope you have missed your first HTML code, For Xpath, it would be better if you give us complete HTML instead of that single element's

Comment: I am not to post both the HTML codes. Posting below

FIRST ONE- 
<input autocomplete="off" class="text" maxlength="30" tabindex="2" type="password" id="pswd-input" name="password" onfocus="
     pswdLabel.style.display='none';pswdWrap.style.margin='0'
     " onblur="
     if(this.value==''){pswdLabel.style.display='block';pswdWrap.style.margin='0 0 -14px'}else{pswdWrap.style.margin='0'}
     ">

SECOND ONE-  
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="35;" autocomplete="off" size="37" value="">==$0

Comment: And where is the code you have tried?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pswd-input'OR @type='password']"));

Comment: Use `or`, not `OR`.

Comment: and it worked... Thank you Guy :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pipe (|) operator

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pswd-input'] | //input[@type='password']"));
```

Comment: So you mean to say driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='pswd-input']")OR("//.*.@type='password']")); is working?

Comment: No, it is working with small or - driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='pswd-input']")or("//.‌​*.@type='password']"‌​));

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pswd-input' or @type='password']"));
```

but why do you need to OR when both versions have type="password" and name="password"? Wouldn't a simple By.name be better? It would match both of these elements:

```
driver.findElements(By.name("password"));
```

Comment: Yes but with the First one it was not working.. it was working only with id='pswd-input'